# Wrong alignment - css

Tags: css, alignment

i have a problem with my alignments on a row with 3 columns and another row with 2 columns.

Like you can see on my screenshot : [Wrong alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsLUC.png)

Here is my code for all the columns : https://jsfiddle.net/1Lcdye4f/

```
#responsive-form{
max-width:1050px 
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
}

.form-row{
width: 100%;
}

.column-four{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0.65rem;
 width:25%;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box
 }

.column-third{
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0.65rem;
width:33%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box
}


.column-half{
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0.65rem;
width:50%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box
 }
```

As you can see on the right sight its not aligned correctly..

I have try different things, but i get stucked. I try to modify the width, position and so on but nothing helped.Hope you can get me in the right direction..?Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Yuk... pastebin... embed your code and include your HTML.

Comment: it is more easy if you use https://jsfiddle.net/ so that we have HTML and CSS

Comment: Done https://jsfiddle.net/1Lcdye4f/. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but with that fiddle we can do nothing!  if you use JS you have to put that one to in

Answer (score 0):

for responsive grids, I have the code to show 3 lines with 4 grid, 3 grids and 2 grids

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.13%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 32.26%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.6%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49.2%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.8%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
</div>

<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
 This is column 1
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
 This is column 2
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
 This is column 3
 </div>
</div>


<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 This is column 1
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 This is column 2
 </div>
</div>
```